# Net Core 3 User role depending on tenant

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a question about managing users and roles in REST services developed with Net Core 3
I am studying how user and role management works in ASP NET Core 3, but I have this doubt: normally a user is associated with a role.

In controller methods, you can then specify for which roles a method will be accessible.
But if the role of my user changes according to the client he is working for, how can I manage it?

Let me explain: the user can access the application and then select which client to work for.
Depending on the customer selected, it could have different roles: Administrator for customer A, Collaborator for customer B, etc.

So the role is not only linked to the user but also to the customer for whom he is operating.
Is it possible to manage this type of authorization with Net Core 3 Identities?

Answer (score 3):

> *"So the role is not only linked to the user but also to the customer for whom he is operating"*:

Firstly, you need a table that stores the Operator-Role-Customer relationship. You could either extends the built-in `AspNetUserRoles` table, or create a brand new table. Since we don't know how your application looks like, I'll create a new table to illustrate how to do that. Let's say we have two operators:

- op1 is both administrator and collaborator for customer 1,
- and op2 is a collaborator for customer 2:

```
 operatorId    |    roleId      |    customerId
---------------+----------------+-----------------
  op1          | Administrator  |        1
---------------+----------------+-----------------
  op1          | Collaborator   |        2
---------------+----------------+-----------------
  op2          | Collaborator   |        2
```

and then instead of using `[Authorize(Roles="xxx")]` directly, we could define a policy of *CheckOperatorRoleForCustomer* that checks the operator-role-customer relationship dynamically:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(opts =>{
    opts.AddPolicy("CheckAdminForCustomer", pb =>{
        pb.RequireAuthenticatedUser().AddRequirements(new OpRoleForCustomerRequirement("Administrator"));
    });
    opts.AddPolicy("CheckCollaboratorForCustomer", pb =>{
        pb.RequireAuthenticatedUser().AddRequirements(new OpRoleForCustomerRequirement("Collaborator"));
    });
});
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, OpRoleForCustomerHandler>();
```

Here the `OpRoleForCustomerHandler` is an [**AuthorizationHandler**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationhandler?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that checks whether the current user has the required role for specified customer.

For convenience, I define two policies here:

- *CheckAdminForCustomer*: check whether the current user has the role of Administrator for specified customer
- *CheckCollaboratorForCustomer*: check whether the current user has the role of Collaborator for specified customer

And then you can apply the policy by :

```
[Authorize(Policy="CheckAdminForCustomer")]
public IActionResult Profile(int CustomerId)
{
```

This pattern is so-called [Policy-Based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which is more powerful than Role-Based Authorization.

Finally, here's my implementation of *OpRoleForCustomerHandler* for your reference:

```cs
public class OpRoleForCustomerRequirement: IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public OpRoleForCustomerRequirement(string RoleId)
    {
        this.RoleId = RoleId;
    }
    public string RoleId{get;set;}
}
public class OpRoleForCustomerHandler: AuthorizationHandler<OpRoleForCustomerRequirement> 
{
    private readonly AppIdentityDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpAccessor;

    public OpRoleForCustomerHandler(AppIdentityDbContext dbContext, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor accessor) 
    {
        this._dbContext = dbContext;
        this._userManager = userManager;
        this._httpAccessor = accessor;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, OpRoleForCustomerRequirement requirement)
    {
        if(context.User==null) { /* ...log... */ context.Fail(); return; }
        var user = await this._userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);

        var httpContext = this._httpAccessor.HttpContext;
        // get customId from HttpContext/RouteData/....
        // for example ....
        var customIdStr = httpContext.Request.Query["customerId"].FirstOrDefault(); 

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customIdStr) ) { 
            var matches = this._dbContext.OpRoleForCustomers
                .Any(opc => 
                    opc.OperatorId == user.Id 
                    && opc.RoleId == requirement.RoleId 
                    && opc.CustmerId == customIdStr
                );
            if(matches){ context.Succeed(requirement) ; return; }
        }
        context.Fail();
    }
}
```

(You might want to custom the way how you get the customId from HttpContext/RouteData/...)

Comment: Thank you for this example with explanation. It helped me a lot to confirm my thoughts as I had a same idea. Only thing I was missing was PolicyBased permissions and custom handler that you made.